Godot 3d Error "E 0:00:05:0814 main.gd:26 @ _process(): Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returning: Transform3D()
I got the error message:
E 0:00:05:0814   main.gd:26 @ _process(): Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returning: Transform3D() <C++ Source>   scene/3d/node_3d.cpp:345 @ get_global_transform() <Stack Trace>  main.gd:26 @ _process() 
In godot 4.3 when i was spawning a object then setting its position, this is my code.
func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    var enimies = $Enemies.get_children()
    if enimies.is_empty() == true:
        print_debug("All enimies killed, next round!")
        stage += 1
        next_stage.emit(stage)
        var scene = load("res://objects/enemy.tscn")
        var enimie = scene.instantiate()
        enimie.player = $Player
        enimie.global_position =  enime_spawns.pick_random()    
        $Enemies.add_child(enimie)

This was my fix
func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    var enimies = $Enemies.get_children()
    if enimies.is_empty() == true:
        print_debug("All enimies killed, next round!")
        stage += 1
        next_stage.emit(stage)
        var scene = load("res://objects/enemy.tscn")
        var enimie = scene.instantiate()
        enimie.player = $Player
        $Enemies.add_child(enimie)
        enimie.global_position =  enime_spawns.pick_random()    

but now it didnt move the object
I tried this
but it doesnt move the object
what i want to happon is that it spawns the object then teleports it
